# Parallel and distribute across npartitions with Dask and PostgreSQL DB

Tags: python, parallel-processing, dask, distributed-computing

I'm trying to consume data from PostgreSQL (host in AWS) with Dask using `dd.read_sql_table()` and passing as argument the full URI SQLAlchemy string `con = f'{dialect}+{driver}://{username}:{password}@{host}:{port}/{database}'`

Is this method **parallelizing the pull down from the DB** or **first pulling down as pandas and then distributing** the data across npartitions with Dask?

I'm aware of dask-sql but the problem is that within `Context()` we already have to provide a dataframe as input, so in some way, first we have to load (lazy or not) our data in our script before putting it into `Context()`

Is there a way to speed up querying a table with multithreading and also distributing across npartitions? Or Dask (obviously distributes) also parallelize the querying under the hood?

I was thinking something about this:

```
def get_dd_from_db(df_chunk):

    dd_from_pool = dd.from_pandas(df=df_chunk)

    return dd_from_pool

def read_sql_chunks(table_name, con, chunksize):

    with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:

        futures = []
        for chunk in pd.read_sql_table(table_name= table_name, con= con, chunksize= chunksize):
            future = executor.submit(chunk)
            futures.append(future)
            
    return futures

def get_pd_from_db(table_name, con, chunksize):

    df_iterator = read_sql_chunks(table_name= table_name, con= con, chunksize= chunksize)
    
    with ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        list(executor.map(lambda chunk:  get_dd_from_db(chunk), df_iterator))
    
    return df
```

A function that parallelize the reading (into pandas df) by chunks and another function that parallelize the writing by chunks into dask dataframe's each partition.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your questions:

> Is this method parallelizing the pull down from the DB or first pulling down as pandas and then distributing the data across npartitions with Dask?

Yes, this method is parallelizing the pull. Depending on the Scheduler type you are using, it will either use threads, processes, or even several servers to pull data by chunks. Pulling down all the rows as Pandas would defeat the benefit of distributed computing.

> Is there a way to speed up querying a table with multithreading and also distributing across npartitions? Or Dask (obviously distributes) also parallelize the querying under the hood?

Dask parallelize or distributes the query. You can customize the number of threads, processes or servers doing that. You can also customize the number of partitions you want (number of chunks), or the volume of each resulting chunk. In the end, performances will also be dependent of your SQL server.

Comment: thank you for your extensive explanation. I'm trying to upload what I pulled down from postgres to bigquery using dask, but it's quite difficult to work arround data types. it seems that dask serialized data through arrow when I try to upload it with load_table_from_dataframe(). it's taking more than I estimated. do you have any experience with uploading data to bigquery using dask?

Comment: No I don't, but I think you should open another post here or in Dask Discourse if you've got a different question.